# My dropdown values binded from user control is setting default values after button click event

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, button, pageload

My page load code:

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            base.PageLoad();
            GetReqPndActTknByMe(base.LogShortID);


            radSLA.DataBind();
            radSLA.SelectedValue = "Yes";
            BindDataToDropdownListAction();
            ucEmployeeDetails.BindDataToCountryDropdownList();
            ucVisaDetails.BindDataToVisaTypeDropdown();
        }
```

I am binding my drop down values using above two methods in to user control.

But when clicking on submit to approve the request my values are setting to default values:

```
  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string requestID = txtRequestID.Text;
            string reqStatus = txtStatusID.Text;
            string actTypeID = ddlAction.SelectedValue;
            int reqType = 40001;


            BVTBusiness.PendingInviteLetter busAction = new CSCI.Portal.Business.VisaTracking.PendingInviteLetter();
            BVTEntity.BusinessVisaRequest entRequest = new CSCI.Portal.Entity.VisaTracking.BusinessVisaRequest();



            entRequest.RequestID = requestID;
            entRequest.ApproverShortID = base.LogShortID;
            entRequest.ActionTypeID = actTypeID;

            if (reqStatus == Constant.WF_STATUS_PEN_WITH_HOME_CM)
            {
                if (actTypeID == "20005" || actTypeID == "20003")
                    entRequest.ApprovalComments = txtActionComments.Text;
                else
                    entRequest.ApprovalComments = "Service Agreement Applicable : " + radSLA.SelectedValue + "       Remarks : " + txtActionComments.Text;
            }

            if (reqStatus == Constant.WF_STATUS_PEN_WITH_OGM)
            {

                if (actTypeID == "20005" || actTypeID == "20003")
                    entRequest.ApprovalComments = txtActionComments.Text;
                else
                    entRequest.ApprovalComments = "Service Agreement Applicable : " + radSLA.SelectedValue + "       Remarks : " + txtActionComments.Text;
            }
            if (reqStatus == Constant.WF_STATUS_PEN_WITH_HOST_CM)
            {

                if (actTypeID == "20005" || actTypeID == "20003")
                    entRequest.ApprovalComments = txtActionComments.Text;
                else
                    entRequest.ApprovalComments = "Service Agreement Applicable : " + radSLA.SelectedValue + "       Remarks : " + txtActionComments.Text;
            }


            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entRequest.ActionTypeID))
            {
                //base.ShowErrorMessage(objLookup.GetMessageInformation(2121).MessageText);
            }
            else
            {

                BVTEntity.BusinessVisaRequest entRetRequest = busAction.SaveApproverActnTkn(entRequest);
                string requestXML = entRetRequest.RequestXML;
                pnlAction.Visible = false;

                BindGrid(requestXML);

                if (actTypeID == "20005")
                {
                    base.ShowMessage("Request Rejected Successfully", Constant.T_INFORMATION);
                }
                else if (actTypeID == "20004")
                {
                    base.ShowMessage("Request Approved Successfully", Constant.T_INFORMATION);
                }
                else if (actTypeID == "20003")
                {
                    base.ShowMessage("Request Send back Successfully", Constant.T_INFORMATION);
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.ShowErrorMessage(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

output after approving:

[image]

my binding function:

```
   public void BindDataToCountryDropdownList()
    {
        BVTBusiness.EmployeeDetails busRequest = new BVTBusiness.EmployeeDetails();
        string countries = busRequest.GetCountries();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(countries))
        {
            countries = "<ITEMS><ITEM CODE=\"0\" CDDesc=\"" + Constant.T_FLDDROP_INTIALTEXT + "\"/></ITEMS>";
        }
        else
        {
            string firstNode = "<ITEMS><ITEM CODE=\"0\" CDDesc=\"" + Constant.T_FLDDROP_INTIALTEXT + "\"/>";
            countries = countries.Replace("<ITEMS>", firstNode);
        }

        dscountrylist.Data = countries;

        ddlTravelFrom.DataBind();
        ddlTravelTo.DataBind();
        ddlCountry.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: view state of usercontrol or dropdownlist is disabled

Comment: where it is disabled and I am not using that view state anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding the dropdown on pageload? I have come across this problem lot many times before and I have never known why it was resolved. Try this below to check if it makes a difference.

```
    ddlProgrammeYear.EnableViewState = true;
```

Otherwise, I would really ask you debug it thoroughly and see when is the dropdown populated with its values.
Also check this to see if you are missing anything: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: yes I am binding it in page load..(!IsPostBack) and when clicking on submit it is not going to (!IsPostBack) and so I am getting default values in dropdown

Comment: try binding the dropdown again. ie. remove the !postback bit. And also try to move the binding to page_init method.